# How do you make it so when you hover over a textbox it shows the blocked cursor?

Tags: html

Im not sure what its name is but i just call it disabled cursor.
Here is a picture of it so you can just tell me Picture of cursor:

[image]

What im trying to do is that when you hover over the text box the cursor shows.
Here is my current code:

```
<input type="text" disabled="" autocomplete="off" id="keyword" name="s" value="" class="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Blocked cursor** can be displayed by rule `cursor: not-allowed`. Pass the `disabled="true"` value to the `:hover` selector.

```css
#keyword[disabled="true"]:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled="true" autocomplete="off" id="keyword" name="s" value="" class="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add to your css `cursor: not-allowed;`